# Как из массива записывать данные в таблицу?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть готовая таблица и массив с объектами.

Как мне в занести данные из этого массива в в мою таблицу?

```
   <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Телефон</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  var contacts = [
  {
    name: 'Ivan',
    surname: 'Ivanov',
    phone: 123123123
  },
  {
    name: 'Iva545n',
    surname: 'Iva5677nov',
    phone: 23123
  }
]

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JavaScript`, понятный новичкам:

```js
var contacts =
[
 {
  name: 'Ivan',
  surname: 'Ivanov',
  phone: 123123123
 },
 {
  name: 'Iva545n',
  surname: 'Iva5677nov',
  phone: 23123
 }
];

var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
{
 var tr = document.createElement('tr');
 tr.innerHTML =
  '<td>' + contacts[i].name + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + contacts[i].surname + '</td>' +
  '<td>' + contacts[i].phone + '</td>';
 tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
table,td
{
 border:1px solid gray
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th scope="col">Имя</th>
  <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
  <th scope="col">Телефон</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let contacts = [{
    name: 'Ivan',
    surname: 'Ivanov',
    phone: 123123123
  },
  {
    name: 'Iva545n',
    surname: 'Iva5677nov',
    phone: 23123
  }
];

const table = document.getElementById('tbody');

for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.innerHTML = `<td>${i+1}</td><td>${contacts[i].name}</td><td>${contacts[i].surname}</td><td>${contacts[i].phone}</td>`;
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
table,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Телефон</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Шаблонные строки и запись через конкатенацию.

```
row.innerHTML = `<td>${i+1}</td><td>${contacts[i].name}</td><td>${contacts[i].surname}</td><td>${contacts[i].phone}</td>`;
row.innerHTML = '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td>' + contacts[i].name + '</td><td>' + contacts[i].surname + '</td><td>' + contacts[i].phone + '</td>';
```

Comment: У вас небольшая ошибка в строчке `row.innerHTML =`

Comment: Можно уточнить, кроме отсутствующей точки с запятой ничего не заметил.

Comment: Спасибо, но я не совсем понимаю ваш синтаксис. Это не чистый джаваскрипт? Не могли бы вы закомментировать строчку с row.innerHTML ? Я вообще не поняла, что вы там делаете, что значат знак "$" ? И обязательно ли объявлять через let вместо var?

Comment: Это чистый javascript, просто стандарт es6. А `$` принадлежит к [шаблонным строковам](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). Можно объявлять переменные и через var.

Comment: У вас там два раза выводиться `${contacts[i].name}` а также не закрыт оидн из `td`, а именно вторая ячейка. И еще, мне кажется не хорошо учить других создавать элементы через `innerHTML`, все же  лучше показать вариант с экранированием специальных символов сразу.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, спасибо, не разглядел, поправил

Answer (score 2):

```js
var contacts = [{
    name: 'Вася',
    surname: 'Пупкин',
    phone: 666666
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    surname: 'Васичкин',
    phone: 23123
  }
]


createTable(document.getElementById('contayner'), contacts);


function createTable(tbody, array) {

  array.forEach(function(items) {

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdName = document.createElement('td');
    var tdSurname = document.createElement('td');
    var tdPhone = document.createElement('td');

    tdName.innerText = items.name;
    tdSurname.innerText = items.surname;
    tdPhone.innerText = items.phone;

    tr.appendChild(tdName);
    tr.appendChild(tdSurname);
    tr.appendChild(tdPhone);
    tbody.appendChild(tr);

  });


} //end createTable
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="contayner"></tbody>
</table>
```