# Как вставить ссылку в src

Tags: javascript

А как сюда фото вставить?
Чтобы в src ссылка залетела.

```html
('<td><img class=“ava” src=“”>' + contacts[i].name + '</img></td>' +)

Что-то типо этого

ava.src = selected.contacts[i].name (Но это не сработало.)
```

Comment: Что такое **ava**? Что такое **selected** и **contacts**? Обновите вопрос, что бы было понятно, что у вас на входе, как вы пытаетесь изменить src и что не получается

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831100/Как-из-массива-записывать-данные-в-таблицу/1492194#1492194


Вот ссылка на вопрос, там написан правильный код, а мне еще нужно в src ссылку загнать

Comment: Там не совсем то. Отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте в него больше кода, что бы было понятно, что и как вы делаете и откуда эти переменные взялись

Comment: Там именно то ,  я делаю таблицу в которую элементы массива заполняются, у меня вставляется текстом ссылка на фото в таблицу, а мне нужно что бы эта ссылка вставала в img-src=“сюда"

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу угадать, какой именно код вы взяли, как его модифицировали и т.д. Покажите его, тогда бдует гораздо понятнее, что у вас пошло не так